# App cannot be downloaded from Google Play because "another account has joined the beta program"

Tags: android, google-play

We recently released an app on google play and after a couple of beta versions I moved it from beta to production. However, some people cannot download the app. Here is an example from Vietnam:

[image]

[image]

I don't know Vietnamese, but I asked a colleague to translate it and it says:

"Another account, {{email}}, has joined the beta program of this app. The updates for this app could include many beta versions."

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: 1. Did you specifiy any beta in PlayConsole? -- 2 Did you try change the App version ?

Comment: I did not change the version number of the release, but promoted it from a beta release; so in the production panel is says: "(Promoted from beta X)" and in the beta panel is says: "Promoted to production"

Would it help to change the release/version name?

Comment: I said to change it in the build.gradle, but I think promote your App would help you in this case. You should read about it before, cause I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Store seems to store the application and user account association information in the device's local storage. **Clearing the data of the Google Play Store** from its app info page should do the trick. Now simply switch the the account that you have joined the beta program with and you should be able to install / update the restricted app version.

If it still doesn't work, repeat the process but this time reboot the device.

Another option is to install the app remotely through [google play's website](https://play.google.com/store/apps). First remove the app from the device, visit the site with the required google account and install the app in the device of your choice remotely.

Comment: This one fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

This should not block updates, it should only be a warning. The English version of the message is "Another account on this device, XXXX, joined this app’s beta program. Updates to this app might include beta versions."
(Good translation by your colleague).

This is a device with more than one gmail account associated with Google Play. It is probably either shared by multiple people or the user has multiple gmail addresses.

An android device can only ever have one version of an APK (with the same package name) on it installed at once, even with multiple users.

The warning is saying that the current account looking for an update is not enrolled in the beta program for the app. However, another account on the device is enrolled in the beta program. This means if this user does an update, they might get a beta version of the app (as the upgrade as to be appropriate for the other user too). The warning is displayed so the user doesn't unexpectedly get a beta version.

However, it should only be a warning, it shouldn't stop the user updating.

Comment: Thanks, so you're saying that the app should definitely already be installed on this particular device?

Comment: No. Just that there is another account which if it were to install the app it would get the beta

Comment: Right, so the problem is there is no way they can install the app (I added a second screenshot); no install button but only the message is shown.

Comment: I would expect this to only happen if the app is already installed

Comment: I've just run into this problem as a user, and I can confirm that it's possible to see this message when the app is **not** installed. In my case I reset my phone to factory settings after joining the beta program with the wrong account. I can install the app, but only if I switch to the account with which I joined the beta program. Maybe this is a bug in the play store?

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to bypass this guys, should you want to install the application. On the app list when you search for the desired application, click on the "..." symbol at the upper right corner of the application, there is an "Install" option for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a button on left top corner, for google play store options. There, change the user to a the one they say that can use the program (different e-mail adress), and you will be able to download the required app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when I wanted to install one app it was saying "another account example@gmail.com on this device joined this app beta program", and I dont see Install button.

In my phone I have multiple gmail accounts and on the Google Play store manage your account section I selected the email account (example@gmail.com) that mentioned on the app page.

After switching to this email account I got Install button for the app which I didn't get before. But after installing the app I noticed that I install (beta) version of the actual app.

So on the app installation page scroll down below to/next to Developer Content, there is an option to Leave the Beta. So click Leave and you can see the actual app with Install button.

Trust this could help someone!